# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character when using json.decode in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, decode

Here is the string am trying to loop through so I have tried to convert it into JSON.

```
{to_address_mobile: [The to address mobile field is required.], to_address_area_number_id: [The to address area number id field is required.]}
```

and here is how i tried to do this :

```dart
          for (var validationError in json.decode('[${resp['data']}]')){
            print(validationError);
          }
```

Every time am getting this error :

```
E/flutter (22342): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3)
E/flutter (22342): [{to_address_mobile: [The to address mobile field is required.], to_address...
```

Comment: Have you tried putting your keys in quotes? `to_address_mobile --> "to_address_mobile"` (also your text values)

Comment: I can't access the source string. I have to handle it like this !! any other way?

Comment: I think you need to parse it yourself, but maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: If you get always this type of data you can easily write a regex pattern for it

Comment: parsing it to add "" for every key and value. I can't find out what pattern can I use to make sure I don't miss anything

Comment: It's probably easier to pull the information out with regex instead of formatting it to json

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a regex pattern to pull the information out of your string. I'm sorry if it's not quite optimal, but I never actually work with regex:

```
(?<key>[^:{\[\] ]*):[ ]*\[(?<value>[^:{\[\]]*)\]
```

The individual matches are the key-value pairs, the keys are in the named group 'key' and the values are in the named group 'value'.